# Who is this news anchor in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification

Throughout the MCU, there are several times when news broadcasts are shown, and I've noticed that throughout a lot of them, they are anchored by the same man. Do we have a name for him? I've noticed him in movies such as *The Avengers*, *Iron Man 3*, etc.

An image from his newscast in *Far From Home*:

[image]

Who is this in-universe? Out of universe, who is he played by?

Comment: @SillyButTrue you don't have to delete your answer just because it says the same thing as another...

Comment: Unless there's some rule or regulation I'm unaware of

Comment: I was posting same thing 40s later. We need  a near-duplicate cluttering up, and that one was better.

Comment: Oh, got it. That makes sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

His name's **[Pat Kiernan](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Pat_Kiernan)**. He's a real-life news anchor who's played himself in various films, both within and without the MCU.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat_Kiernan):

> Patrick Kiernan (born November 20, 1968) is a Canadian-American television host, appearing as the morning news anchor of [NY1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NY1) since 1997. He is widely known in New York City for his "In the Papers" feature, in which he summarizes the colorful content in New York City's daily newspapers, replete with his deadpan humor. Kiernan has also hosted game shows and appeared in films and on television either as himself or as a reporter.

From [The Direct](https://thedirect.com/article/spider-man-hawkeye-far-from-home-anchor):

> Hawkeye's first episode featured the return of Pat Kiernan, the same real-life reporter who appeared in *The Avengers*, *Iron Man 3*, *Doctor Strange*, and, most recently, *Spider-Man: Far From Home*.
>
> Kiernan can be seen on a TV news report, revealing details about the new Ronin that resurfaced during an attack on a high-class gala in New York.
>
> Aside from MCU films, Kiernan has also been featured in Marvel's Netflix shows, namely *Daredevil*, *The Punisher*, and *The Defenders*.
>
> Kiernan has been serving as the morning news anchor of NY1 since 1997, and the journalist has been appearing in several films based in New York throughout his storied career. The news anchor appeared in films like *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*, *Night at the Museum*, and *Jack Ryan: Shadow Recruit*.
>
> <sub>Spider-Man: Far From Home News Anchor Spotted In Hawkeye Premiere</sub>

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense.

Comment: “The news anchor appeared in films like The Amazing Spider-Man 2” — Pat Kiernan, journalist right across the multiverse.

Comment: He's like Uatu the Watcher but he tells you about what he saw.  Kiernan the Reporter